# Image generation from Radar (IMAGEVK-74) I/Q signals

Tags: radar, array-signal-processing

I have a millimeter wave radar ([IMAGEVK-74](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/imagevk_74.html)). I am new to signal processing and I need to generate images from the radar data.

The specifications of the radar are- it has a 20 transmitter 20 receivers antenna configuration giving 400 Tx-Rx pairs. It is working at multiple frequencies (21 currently) between 62-69 GHz. The radar scans 300 times per sample. Further details shown below:

{'mode': 'low framerate', 'frequency_limits': {'min': 62000.0, 'max': 69000.0, 'points': 21.0}, 'rbw': 30.0, 'antenna_pair_limit': 400, 'scans_per_single_sample': 300, 'scan_repeats': 1}

The Python code I am using to operate the radar returns the I/Q data for the 400 antenna pairs, for 300 sample points and 21 frequency points, returning an array of 300x400x21.

**Question:** I want to use the radar to image a surface with patches of different reflectivity surfaces. I want to produce a 2D image from the generated I/Q data, however, as I am new to the field, I am unsure how it is done. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. I am reading the array processing theory, and suggestions on what theoretical aspects I need to know would be helpful as well.

Comment: I have the same problem, I am new to radar, you already know how to make an image with the I/Q signals. if the answer is yes. Could you share with me how you do it?